# Android: Edit views added programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, view

So I have a messaging app where I read my database and render all the messages programatically. The thing is, when I am inside a different layout, I need to inflate those messages and edit them at will. For example,

```
val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.female_messaging_fragment, container, false)
...

val convLayout = myView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.conversations_layout)
val profileLayout = LinearLayout(context)

 val recentMessage = TextView(context)
 recentMessage.id = 5



val recentParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

            recentParams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0)

            recentMessage.layoutParams = recentParams
            recentMessage.textSize = 16f
            if (didIsendLastMessage) {
                val arrowIcon = ImageView(context)
                Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.right_arrow).resize(50, 50).into(arrowIcon)
                val imageParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                imageParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                arrowIcon.layoutParams = imageParams
                recentMessage.setText(mostRecentMessage)
                arrowAndMessageLayout.addView(arrowIcon)
                arrowAndMessageLayout.addView(recentMessage)
            } else {
                recentMessage.setText(mostRecentMessage)
                arrowAndMessageLayout.addView(recentMessage)
            }


            nameLastmessageLayout.addView(arrowAndMessageLayout)


            // Add namne and message to profile
            profileLayout.addView(nameLastmessageLayout)
convLayout.addView(profileLayout)
```

And then in a different layout...

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.female_messaging_fragment, null);
TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(5);
text.setText("Something");
```

The thing is, text is always null, and I believe it is because I added the views programatically. What else can I do here? Thanks!

Comment: Show how, exactly, you're adding the views programmatically.  Right now it looks like you're not adding them.

Comment: @RyanMentley Added, I should have done this before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

inflating `female_messaging_fragment` will return fresh new Layout view object of your xml that might be blank layout without any TextViews.

To get TextView object you need the object of Layout in which you had added the views.

For example as per your code you added `recentMessage` in `arrowAndMessageLayout` so to get the object of `recentMessage` you need the object of `arrowAndMessageLayout` and can get like below -

```
TextView text = arrowAndMessageLayout.findViewById(5);
```

OR

```
TextView text = convLayout.findViewById(5);
```

Inflating again will return fresh new container without your textview.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I go about getting the text when I am not inside of the same class/layout? Since convLayout and arrowAndMessageLayout are not layouts inside of R.layouts, I don't know how to fetch them. Thank you.

Comment: you can use interface and implement in that class where you inflated myView  and call from the class where you want to get the object of convLayout or arrowAndMessageLayout. you can declare convLayout as Instance variable.

Comment: Thanks again man haha, one more question. What if I can't implement / extend the class? For example, it's a fragment so it must implement Fragment() itself, so it can't be an interface. Thanks again!

Comment: can you share me the both classes where you inflated myView and the class where you want to get the Textview object?

Comment: @DipankarBaghel i have some doubts how i can contact you?